# Is there a way to specific what GMAIL, mac Mail, iOS Mail shows as the email preview?

Tags: ios, email, gmail

Right now it appears that Gmail and iOS Mail simply take as much text as possible from the HTML template. Is there any way to control what is displayed in the mail preview for mail clients?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Gmail displays the first 100 or so characters of an email, minus the subject length. If the first paragraph ends before this limit, it will only show this much.

iOS devices show about 80 characters, again with much the same rules.

There's no setting that you can send through to determine what gets displayed as the preview in an email.